# Selecting random value for every row

Tags: sql, oracle, random

Suppose I have 2 tables called 'FOR_TEST_1' with column A, B, C and 'FOR_TEST_2' with column D, E, F.

I would like to generate column A paired with a random value from column D.

Here is a snippet of the tables.

[image: Table FOR_TEST_1]

[image: Table FOR_TEST_2]

So far, this is the statement that I have been doing and it return the same value of D for every row in A.

[image: Query result]

Currently I am using toad for oracle, but I tried using the same logic in MySQL and it works fine.

Comment: What's question here?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you for bringing the meta up to me and I'm sorry for not reading it before posting. I will keep it mind for future posts

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting Oracle to execute the subquery once per row (which is what MySQL does). However, it seems you have run into a side-effect of an Oracle optimization. There's no correlation between the main query and the scalar subquery so Oracle decides to un-nest the subquery, execute it once and join the result to the main query.

To get the results you want you have a couple of options. One is to turn off the unnesting with the `NO_UNNEST` hint.

```
select   t1.a
       ,  ( select d from ( select /*+ NO_UNNEST */  d from for_test_two 
            order by dbms_random.value ) where rownum = 1) d
from for_test_one t1
/
```

Alternatively you could rewrite you query to use an inline view rather than a scalar subquery.

```
select t1.a
       , t2.d
from ( select a, rownum as rn 
        from for_test_one) t1
     join ( select d, rownum as rn 
         from ( select d from for_test_two 
                order by dbms_random.value() ) ) t2
     on t1.rn = t2.rn
order by t1.rn
/
```

---

**Warning**: The `NO_UNNEST` solution doesn't work on SQL Fiddle demo ([find it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fce67/1)). Not sure why, the syntax looks correct. So try it on your environment, or just use the second approach, which definitely works.

Comment: Excellent!. I was about to answer giving just the 2nd solution. But, great to know we have the first one  as well. +1

Comment: Hi, I tried using the no unnest hint but it returns the same result as the query I mention in the question.

Also, the second query limit the row in A to be equal to the number of row in column D. In this case, I have 10 row in A and 5 in D and the query return a total of 5 row because of join. 
Is there anyway of getting a result with full row of column A? (returns 10 row)

Comment: You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the second table. That will return values of `d` for the first five rows and null thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A, (SELECT D (
           SELECT D, ROWNUM ROWPTR FROM FOR_TEST_2)
           WHERE ROWPTR = (SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, (SELECT COUNT(D) FROM FOR_TEST_2) + 1 )) from DUAL)) D 
FROM FOR_TEST_1
```

Comment: This returns NULL value from the D column